# How to LIMIT a recursive SELECT query at each step?

Tags: sql, recursion, mariadb

I'm trying to write a recursive SELECT query that walks a graph stored in a database (MariaDB 10.2.6).  The nodes of my graph are labeled with two coordinates - let's call them x and y.  The graph is constructed so that there are edges between (x,y) and (x-1,y), (x,y-1), and (x-1,y-1).  Each edge is then ranked by a function that depends on a difference in values associated with each node (e.g. f(n1,n2) = n2.value - n1.value, where n1 and n2 are two nodes that share an edge).

To make this more complicated, suppose the edge function is different for the case of (x,y) -> (x-1,y) than for the other cases.  Call the function for this case f1, and for the other cases f2.

What I want to do is traverse this graph from an arbitrary starting point according to the following rules:

- x and y may never increase during a step;
- If there is a node (x-1,y) that satisfies f1 < (some cutoff value), always take this step;
- Otherwise take one of (x,y-1) or (x-1,y-1) that minimizes f2;
- If (x,y-1) and (x-1,y-1) do not exist, fall back to (x-1,y).
- Finally, if there are no suitable neighbors, the recursive query should terminate.

Right now I'm trying to do with using a recursive SELECT query like the following:

```
WITH RECURSIVE step (
  id,    -- step number
  tid,   -- substep number
  nid,   -- node id
  x,     -- node x
  y,     -- node y
  f      -- value of f between the previous and current nodes
)
AS
(
  -- Initial step.
  SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS tid, n1.id AS nid, n1.x, n1.y, 0.0 AS f
  FROM nodes AS n1 WHERE n1.x = initial_x AND n1.y = initial_y

  -- Begin the recursive part.
  UNION ALL
    -- Use a subquery here so we can limit each step.
    SELECT * FROM (

    -- First part of the subquery checks (x-1,y).
    SELECT step.id + 1 AS id, 1 AS tid, n2.id AS nid,
           n2.x, n2.y, f1(v1.value, v2.value) AS f
    FROM step
    INNER JOIN values v1 ON v1.node = step.nid
    INNER JOIN nodes n2 ON (n2.x = step.x - 1 AND n2.y = step.y)
    INNER JOIN values v2 ON v2.node = n2.id
    WHERE f < some_cutoff

    -- Second part of the subquery checks (x,y-1) and (x-1,y-1).
    UNION
    SELECT step.id + 1 AS id, 2 AS tid, n2.id AS nid,
           n2.x, n2.y, f2(v1.value, v2.value) AS f
    FROM step
    INNER JOIN values v1 ON v1.node = step.nid
    INNER JOIN nodes n2 ON (n2.x = step.x AND n2.y = step.y - 1)
                        OR (n2.x = step.x - 1 AND n2.y = step.y - 1)
    INNER JOIN values v2 ON v2.node = n2.id

    -- Third part again selects (x-1,y) but without cutoff condition.
    UNION
    SELECT step.id + 1 AS id, 3 AS tid, n2.id AS nid,
           n2.x, n2.y, f1(v1.value, v2.value) AS f
    FROM step
    INNER JOIN values v1 ON v1.node = step.nid
    INNER JOIN nodes n2 ON n2.x = step.x - 1 AND n1.y = step.y
    INNER JOIN values v2 ON v2.node = n2.id

    ) a    -- give the subquery a dummy name

    -- At the end of the recursive step, sort and take the first step.
    ORDER BY tid, f ASC LIMIT 1

)

-- Get the list of steps.
SELECT * FROM step ORDER BY id ASC;
```

My thought here is basically to divide the three conditions into three unioned subqueries, each with an increasing rank (tid).  At the end of each recursive step, I order by this rank, then order by the value of f within each rank.  This should leave me with a set of rows with the most preferable node at the top.  Finally, I use LIMIT 1 to select the most favorable node, and the recursion continues.  When I reach the node with no suitable neighbors (x_min, y_min), the subquery should return an empty set, and recursion should terminate.

Unfortunately, this query isn't working for me right now.  MariaDB hangs whenever I try to execute it, and I'm not sure why.  My obvious first thought is that the recursion is never terminating (infinite loop), but I believe the INNER JOINs on the decreasing x and y should prevent this.  Am I missing something important here/not understanding how to use recursive queries correctly?  Is there a better way to approach this type of problem?

Comment: It's MariaDB 10.2.6; according to the docs (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/), recursive WITH has been supported since MariaDB 10.2.2.  I added the MySQL tag since they're so closely related, I'll remove it if appropriate.

Comment: mysql <> mariadb.

Comment: My bad, thanks for correcting me.  Tag removed.